# Create a Pivot table of a column values both at rows and column and count only the common values between the relation

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, pivot

So I have the data like below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Customer':'Alan John Mike'.split(' ') * 3,
                   'Price':[111,222,333,444,444,222,666,111,333]})
```

[Souce Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HQiY3.png)

I want to count the unique matching `Price` across the `customers` in 2 * 2 matrix and want the output like below:

[image]

**I have the pivot function below but it returns just a count across matching Customers:**

```
pvt = pd.pivot_table(df,index=['Customer'],columns=['Customer'], aggfunc={'Price':lambda x: x.nunique()})
```